# What is the link to question intuitive understanding of $\sum \frac{1}{k2^k}=\ln 2$?

Tags: support, specific-question

What is the link to question intuitive understanding of $\sum \frac{1}{k2^k}=\ln 2$ ?
I tried google and various ways, including walking the list questions in the chronological order as far I thought it might be relevant to no avail.

Thank you for your help

PS: I am sure I saw that question, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's post [55505](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55505), with URL `https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55505`.  Those who have under 10000 points and are not moderators will not be able to view it at that link, because it was deleted by the owner about 18 minutes after it was posted.

Comment: There is a Google cache at http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:nXqqnV93y2QJ:math.stackexchange.com/questions/55505/reason-for-the-expansion-displaystyle-log-2-sum-k-1-infty-frac1k2k

Comment: This is definitely a wonderful privilege of the 10K club! :-)

Comment: Asaf: Yes, but unfortunately it isn't easy to find deleted posts.  It used to be, and there's a feature request on meta.SO to have that ability again: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92979/restore-the-10k-ability-to-see-all-closed-deleted-posts-in-a-list.  (In this case, I had visited the question before it was deleted, and I found it in my browser history.)